# How can I tell if someone is logged into a google account?

Tags: google, html, php

At this point I don't want to interface w/ google account, I just would like to know if they are logged in to a google account or not, and then serve slightly different links if they are|aren't. I'm using PHP and strict (where possible) HTML 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using Google as an OpenID provider I don't think there is any way to know. That kind of information is kept off limits as a security precaution.

Comment: There was a method discussed in the answer on this SO post, however, it's doubtful that the method will work reliably for organizations which have an interest in maintaining users' privacy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233560/possible-to-find-out-whether-a-user-is-logged-into-facebook-over-javascript-api

Comment: One day the Internet will be secure. I just hope it's in my lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not possible. What you are trying to do is to access the type of information others would not want to share with you. I know this does not address your question directly but maybe there is another way to achieve what you want to achieve?